# Jquery autocomplete not able to search in middle or end in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

> I am using a a simple jquery autocomplete, in one of my input field in
> JSP,using below code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#MyAutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source : document.getElementById(myDataList).ToArray()
    });
});
```

> In JSP,

```
<datalist id="myDataList"></datalist>
<input name="MyAutoComplete" id="MyAutoComplete" size="37" list="myDataList"  type="text"></td>
```

> Datalist is getting populated with an script call when page is
> loading, which in turn calling Action and DAO classes, to fetch
> objects from DB and filling the list.
>
> Now problem is, say I have three
> String in my list, "Bob is a good cat", "We have a cat named Bob",
> "Cat Bob is funny". When searching in jsp field with Bob in Mozila/Chrome all
> three of them are coming , which is correct, as all of them has Bob in
> them, but in IE only "Bob is a good cat" is coming, as that is the
> only string starting with Bob, its not able to search in middle or end, I am not sure what is the issue here. Please help.
>
> I am using jquery-1.10.2.js, jquery-ui.js.

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with JSP since you are on client side. If the list is complet, I would guess that JQuery is using different logic based on browser.

Comment: Correct, My code works great, in everywhere other than IE, I have tried posting this in jquery forum, but not much luck, not sure, why IE is behaving such way.

Comment: I could simply say "because IE !" ;) More seriously, autocomplete is a feature dependent of the browser so this is probably not so well made in the javascript core of IE, limiting the results to the String starting with your input. (To be confirmed of course.)